# What selenium package in NuGet do I install that includes function "isDisplayed"?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What package in Nuget do I install for selenium that includes function "isDisplayed"? And what name do I use to use it in my project?

Comment: See following : https://www.automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-csharp-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Still. There's no display function :/

Comment: IMO, you don't need any extra C# package to implement `isDisplayed()`

Comment: The link shows : bool isDisplayed = element.Displayed;

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the Displayed extension on a WebElement.

Example

```
var element = WebDriver.FindElementById("Login");
if (element.Displayed) {
Console.WriteLine("I'm displayed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? Nowadays, in each professional IDE is autocomplete, which will help you to call `isDisplayed();` method.

Method `isDisplayed();` is abstract and located in WebElement.class